# Bootstrap horizontal line stretches to the enire width of computer screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In the following I want horizontal line to take only the width of 4 columns. But it stretches to the entire screen width.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <hr />
    This is a test
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? Please post it.

Comment: @ZimSystem Thank you for reading the post. It's an ASP.NET Core web app. Which part of the code you would recommend I post that may be relevant to diagnosing the issue?